# Which custom recovery to use for Chinese Samsung Note 3 Neo SM-N7506V?

Tags: custom-roms, clockworkmod-recovery

I bought a Samsung of the above mentioned model here in China and I want to flash Gapps on it. I understand the process to do so is

1. rooting it,
2. flash a custom recovery program like CWM or TWRP
3. install the gapps zip in the recovery mode of the phone.

I successfully rooted it via Odin and C-Flash.
The problem I encounter is that **I can't find a custom recovery that works on my model.**

CWM does not offer any. 
I tried TWRP, but with this my phone got bricked and I needed to install a new firmware. 
Repeated googling did not produce any answers to my questions.

Please help me out,  I would be happy to use gapps as on a European phone.

Comment: Try putting all .so files from the zip into /system/lib and all apk files to /system/priv-app (4.4+) or /system/app (<4.4)